# Why is clang-format screwing up this code?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

My code base has a lot of `std::variant` types and functions that use `std::visit` to implement different behavior based on the actual type.

I am using `clang-format`, and sometimes it scrambles the functions that use `std::visit`. I have a function called `visitor` that builds a visitor from a bunch of lambdas. It appears that when the lambdas declare a return type of `auto&`, `clang-format` decides to start breaking lines after the closing brace of each lambda, leaving the commas on the left margin.

Here is a sample function, with the `clang-format` formatting:

```
struct A {};
struct B {};
typedef std::variant<A, B> AB;

template <class... Ts>
struct visitor : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator()...;
};
template <class... Ts>
visitor(Ts...) -> visitor<Ts...>;

AB& f(AB& ab) {
    auto v = visitor{[&](const A& a) -> auto& {std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    return ab;
}
, [&](const B& b) -> auto& {
    std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    return ab;
}
,
};
std::visit(v, ab);
}
```

Here's how it should look (which I get if I remove `-> auto&`):

```
AB& f(AB& ab) {
    auto v = visitor{
        [&](const A& a) {
            std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
            return ab;
        },
        [&](const B& b) {
            std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
            return ab;
        },
    };
    std::visit(v, ab);
}
```

Here is my `.clang-format` file:

```
BasedOnStyle:  Google
ColumnLimit: 120
IndentWidth: 4
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
```

I'm using Clang 9.

Does anyone how know I can fix this?

Comment: there seem to be an extra comma after the second lambda

Comment: @user7860670 Trailing commas, while not part of C++, are a Clang extension. If removing the comma fixes it, then that would confirm a clang-format bug.

Comment: Removing the extra comma doesn't fix it.